# Modify connection string in nTier code first project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, n-tier-architecture

I have a 4 tier web api project :

Web Api -
Entities -
Business Logic -
Data Access

..and I am using code first with an empty context constructor so the connection string is picked up from the web.config in my Web Api project :

```
 public MyContext() : base()
    {

    }
```

Question is, can I read the serverName and databaseCatalog from a .settings file and modify the connection string at runtime?

Comment: You use TableAdapter object to connect on DataBase ?

Comment: yES YOU CAN CHANGE YOUR CONNECTION STRING AT RUN TIME. BY PASSING CONNECTIONSTRING AS FOLLOWS:  USING(MyContext CONTEXT = NEW MyContext(NEWCONNECTIONSTRING)) {}

Comment: thanks for the reply, I should have made my question clearer as I am looking for a way to read a .settings file in the WebApi and modify the connection string 3 layers down in the DAL, I was hoping there might be a tidier way than passing the connection string as method parameters as I have quite a lot going on in between!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building the connection string in the business layer and passing it down through layers in the constructor.